# HTML Doctype & css hack

Tags: html, css

I'm trying this html code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body { background-color : green !important; background-color : red; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
Hello World !
</body>
</html>
```

In firefox, it's working fine : green background.
In internet explorer : it's not working : also green background.

If I remove the doctype, it's working fine in both.
I tried different doctypes but always the same problem.

What can I do ?

Comment: Not sure if trolling, or just disbelief that IE can actually follow standards.

Comment: Just use `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`. Go with the flow!. Also what version of Firefox and what version of IE? because if it is IE6 or IE11, that kinda matters.

Comment: "What's not working?" -> the css hack.  Without doctype : geen in firefox and red with ie.  With doctype green in both cases.

Comment: so, uh, what exactly are you saying? are you trying to say you *want* it to be different in IE? Why?

Comment: IE6, IE7, IE8, IE9, IE10 or IE11: question from @1ntello is an important one. Also are you testing a file:/// resource, in localhost, shared network or on a normal domain domain.com?

Comment: yeah I think with no DOCTYPE IE puts it in Quirks mode or IE 5 engine, so seriously. Use just <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: @Spudley - Ok I know this example is stupid but much more easy the explain the problem.  The question is : why css hack seems not working with doctype definition ?

Comment: I guess I'm missing something...what CSS hack is being used?

Comment: @FelipeAls - ie 10 - ff 24.

Answer (score 5):

> Ok I know this example is stupid but much more easy the explain the problem. The question is : why css hack seems not working with doctype definition ?

There is no hack there. There's a `!important` declaration, which is standard CSS, but wasn't supported properly by IE5.

If you take away the doctype, IE will go into quirks mode, which is basically an IE5-emulation mode. Therefore it will use the IE5 CSS rules, which means that `!important` doesn't work (along with a whole bunch of other features).

So without a doctype, in quirks mode, it ignores `!important`, and so both your rules have the same precedence, and thus the second one (`red`) is used.

With a doctype, the browser will be in standards mode, and `!important` works the way it should do, which means that `green` takes precedence because it's 'important'.

I still don't get what you're trying to achieve, but hopefully that explains to you what is going on.

Comment: My goal is of course not changing the background color but changing label alignment of checkboxes in a complicated form (generated by jsf2) and that is not displayed in the same way with ff and ie

Comment: @tweetysat, isn't that just a completely different problem?

Comment: @tweetysat: without a doctype, you're in quirks mode. In addition to breaking the `!important` feature, quirks mode also changes some of the basic layout properties of the rendering engine, and disables a lot of other browsers features, which will indeed often make a page look quite different in IE compared to other browsers. This is why you should avoid quirks mode (and thus why you should always use a doctype). I guess this question is pretty moot now; I suggest starting again with a fresh question that describes the actual problem you're having with the form.